# Denial of Service - http proxy - React

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy, denial-of-service

I am pretty sure that this error appeared only today and it never occurred before.
When I create a new react app, the process found 1 high vulnerability:

**High:**            Denial of Service

**Package:**         http-proxy

**Patched in:**    No patch available

**Dependency of:**   react-scripts

**Path:**  react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > http-proxy-middleware >  http-proxy

**More info:**       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1486

(My version of "`react-scripts`" is **3.4.1**). Of course, "`npm audit fix`" doesn't work.

What can I do about it? Is it something to care about or I can work normally?

Comment: There is a issue on github about this https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1446.

Comment: The advisory given in https://npmjs.com/advisories/1486 states that there is no fix available, yet. This is due to the fact that this vulnerability report has been added just today and needs to be evaluated further.

Comment: Should we stop running npm audit in the meantime?

Comment: Same problem happened to me today

Comment: A DoS vulnerability usually means there is a way to abuse the module to quickly take down your app without too much effort. If your http proxy is public-facing then this could be an issue. There is nothing you can do about until there’s a fix.

Comment: Feel free to ignore the error in the meantime this is not a big problem to a server that is not exposed to the internet and the impact would just be your dev env crashing not production.

Answer (score 4):

All versions of http-proxy are vulnerable to Denial of Service. An HTTP request with a long body triggers an ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT unhandled exception that crashes the proxy server. This is only possible when the proxy server sets headers in the proxy request using the proxyReq.setHeader function.

For a proxy server running on http://localhost:3000, the following curl request triggers the unhandled exception:
curl -XPOST http://localhost:3000 -d "$(python -c 'print("x"*1025)')"

## Remediation

No fix is currently available. Consider using an alternative package until a fix is made available.

## Conclusion

But for the time being, you can work normally. It should not cause any type of working anomaly as of now.

Comment: It will break ci pipeline though

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to http-proxy 1.18.1+ which contains a fix for the security issue detailed. NPM have now updated their security APIs to include the information that this issue is now resolved.

See https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1446 for more info

Answer (score -1):

first install the package

npm install http-proxy --save-dev

in your package.json file add the following statements

"resolutions" :{
"http-proxy": "^1.18.1"
}

"scripts" :{
"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}

then run the command in the command prompt-

npm install

this might fixed your vulnerability